# Is the encryption passphrase presented on install required if I have a luks header backup?

Tags: system-installation, security, encryption, data-recovery, luks

After installing Lubuntu 16.04 with LUKS full drive encryption and LVM I was presented with a long passphrase to record for recovery purposes.

I'm assuming this is the "true" encryption key that my LUKS key / boot password unlocks. If so, do I need to record it if I am keeping a LUKS header backup on some removable media?

I assume that with this passphrase all data could be recovered from the drive, even if the LUKS header was corrupted and no backup available. And that if this passphrase is leaked then all data would be up for grabs.
Is this right?

I just want to be sure I understand correctly what this passphrase is for and the risks / usefulness associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are asking about the master key, and if so, yes the master key can be used for data recovery and decrypt your data. The intention is to give you a way of decrypting the LUKS container in the event you lost your password.

> If the header is intact and you just forgot the passphrase, just set a
>   new passphrase like this:

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey --master-key-file=<master-key-file> <luks device>
```

For details see - https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#6-backup-and-data-recovery

The master key, password, and luks header, and how to use them, are discussed in great detail on that page and I am not sure how to further answer your question.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's the master key as shown in that FAQ. 
The installation said "Record your encryption passphrase" and then displayed a 32 character string.
I'm on a similarly installed PC right now and the master key is much longer than that.
I've previously read that FAQ you posted. But this seems to be an Ubuntu install specific dialog box and I'm not sure what it is giving me.

Comment: Try using it as a master key ;)